# Undefined property error message in PHP OOP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm working on a custom CMS using PHP OOP and this is actually my first project ever which is made with object oriented programming so I don't have that much of experience with it. Basically I have a class called `Site.class.php` which retrieves data from one of the tables in MySQL database and goes like this:

```
    <?php 
class Site
{
    public $id,$site_name,$site_title,$site_url,$site_tags,$site_desc;
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->db = new Connection();
        $this->db = $this->db->dbConnect();
    }
    public function getSite($name)
    {
        if(!empty($name))
        {
            $site = $this->db->prepare("select * from admins where site_name = ?");
            $site->bindParam(1,$name);
            $site->execute();
            while($row = $site->fetch())
            {
                $this->id           = $row['id'];
                $this->site_name    = $row['site_name'];
                $this->site_title   = $row['site_title'];
                $this->site_url     = $row['site_url'];
                $this->site_tags    = $row['site_tags'];
                $this->site_desc    = $row['site_desc'];
            }
        }
        else
        {
            header("Location: maint/php/includes/errors/005.php");
            exit();
        }
    }
    public function getID()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }
    public function getSiteName()
    {
        return $this->site_name;
    }
    public function getSiteTitle()
    {
        return $this->site_title;
    }
    public function getSiteUrl()
    {
        return $this->site_url;
    }
    public function getSiteTags()
    {
        return $this->site_tags;
    }
    public function getSiteDesc()
    {
        return $this->site_desc;
    }
}
?>
```

I have included this file at another file which is called `settings.php` and called it in this way:

```
$siteSet = new Site();
$siteSet->getSite("Daygostar");
```

Then I tried echoing out the variables like this:

```
<div class="box-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="usr">Site Name:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usr" disabled='disabled' value="<?php echo $siteSet->getSiteName; ?>">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="usr">User URL:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usr" disabled='disabled' value="<?php echo $siteSet->getSiteUrl; ?>">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

But the problem is that whenever I call this file ,I receive this error message:

> **Undefined property: Site::$getSiteName**
>
> **Undefined property: Site::$getSiteUrl**

I don't know what's really going wrong because I have coded everything correctly! So if you know how to solve this question please let me know, I really appreciate that.. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Side note: You will save yourself a few lines if you do a `__call($name)` method and remove all those methods that call variables. Inside the magic method, you can do `$split = preg_split('/(?=[A-Z])/', $name); $var = strtolower($split[1].'_'.$split[2]); return $this->{$var};` so that when you do `$obj->getSiteName();` it will dynamically return `$this->site_name`. Saves you from writing a whole bunch of methods that mechanically do the exact same thing. Something to think about.

Comment: I think it's awesome that you are jumping right in with OOP. Go for it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are both methods. You need to add the () to the end of them to invoke the method.

```
<div class="box-body">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="usr">Site Name:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usr" disabled='disabled' value="<?php echo $siteSet->getSiteName(); ?>">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="usr">User URL:</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usr" disabled='disabled' value="<?php echo $siteSet->getSiteUrl(); ?>">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```